# Perforce verify checksum before flush?

Tags: command-line, version-control, perforce

In perforce manuals about [p4 flush](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/cmdref/p4_flush.html), they say it's dangerous operation.

Because it does not actually transfer files. but I was thinking if it's possible to make this less dangerous by first verifying the checksum of files, then performing the flush if checksum are equal.

Me and my friend have identical files in our workspace, but the files are too big, and it takes time to upload them on the server. so when the upload is finished, I want to make sure that files are still identical.

we could calculate SHA-1 of our workspace and manually make sure files are still identical. (we are working on a unreal engine project with lots of binary files and some files might be changed by now.)

also the project contains some ignored files and we have to make sure to exclude them from checksum.

does perforce perform this verification by itself? or is there a command(or script) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p4 diff -se` command will tell you whether your unopened workspace files match the corresponding depot revisions.

For your particular use case, I'd recommend skipping that step; if you follow `p4 flush` with `p4 clean`, it will force a re-sync of everything that doesn't match the depot (but only those files).

Comment: I just tested and reconcile works as expected, thanks a lot